# Assign same menu class to body jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick, onload

I have a problem. I have a menu like this:

```
<ul id="mainmenu" class="meganizr mzr-slide mzr-responsive">
<li id="menu_435" class="style1 menu_1 active">
<li id="menu_469" class="style5 menu_1 mzr-drop parent">
<li id="menu_475" class="style3 menu_1 mzr-drop parent">
<li id="menu_507" class="style4 menu_1">
<li id="menu_540" class="style5 menu_1 mzr-drop parent">
<li id="menu_559" class="style6 menu_1">
</ul>
```

My question is related to `class="style6"`. When the menu is active, I want the class `style6` assigned to body. Example: <`body class="style6"`. How can I do this?

Comment: how do decide whether it is active? on which event?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you decide the active status by clicking on style6 in menu,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li[class^="style6 menu_1 active"]').click(function(){
        $('body').attr('class','style6');
    }); 
});
```